# InnoDB relationships: one-way or two-way?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, foreign-keys, innodb

I've decided for the first time to switch to InnoDB and experiment with foreign keys and other InnoDB features.

When creating relationships, should I declare them only on 1 table? Or both tables?

For example, for each cases below, where and how would you declare the relationships?

- 1 User has many widgets
- widget belongs to 1 user (is that same as above?)
- 1 user has 1 widget
- user [many-to-many] widgets
- many users share 1 widget

Those are just some random examples, I'm just trying to understand which directions relationships should be declared.

Also, on the same note, which direction do "ON CASCADE" stuff work?

Thanks

Comment: Is there a chance that other users will share the same widget?

Comment: yes, I added this scenario now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- 1 User has many widgets

Assuming a widget is exclusive to one user (because you have a seperate point for many to many): `user_id` on table `widget` that references the primary key on `user`

- widget belongs to 1 user

see above.

- 1 user has 1 widget

`widget_id` in `user` table that references primary key on `widget` table, with unique index on `widget_id`, or the other way around, doesn't really matter. If it is a 1-to-1 and not a 0 or 1-to-1 relationship, you should consider putting widget and user in one table.

- user [many-to-many] widgets

Introduce a third table, `user_widget`, with 2 fields `user_id` and `widget_id` referencing the corresponding primary keys in user and widget table.

- many users share 1 widget

same as "1 user has 1 widget", but without a unique index on  the `widget_id`

The `ON CASCADE` option works from parent (primary key) to child (foreign key/reference). So if you have a `ON DELETE CASCADE` in your first scenario (1 User has many widgets), delete a user deletes all his widgets, but deleting all widgets doesn't delete the user.

Comment: How does it know who is the parent and who is the child? It seems in case 1 the ON DELETE will be declared in the child table (widget), while in case 3 it will be declared in the parent (user).

Comment: Case 3 can go either way, because you have a 1-to-1 relation. What yo usually do in case 3, if you have a true 1-to-1, is just add the widget columns to user. If it is a 0..1 to 1 (widget is not necessary), then the FK is in widget and thus becomes the child.

Comment: I'm starting to see it more clearly. Thanks. Basically the initial answer is it's ONE-WAY. Everything links from the foreign key to a primary key. And since there is only 1 declaration, well that's where I would put my CASCADE if necessary.

Comment: The ON UPDATE/DELETE [RESTRICT | CASCADE | SET NULL | NO ACTION] is defined on the foreign key, but triggered if the referenced row (the primary key) is updated/deleted.

Comment: I'm using Yii to generate Models, and using this method, the generated code makes sense. Perfect!